# How to add brackets into group_concat using knex

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, string

Hey guys I'm using knex with MySQL. I want to add brackets to my field. I'm using group_concat but I get an answer without brackets

```js
knex('cardex').rightJoin('cardex_agelimit' , 'cardex.id' , 'cardex_agelimit.CardexId')
.select( knex.raw('group_concat( DISTINCT (ages.AgeTitle) ) as ages , group_concat( DISTINCT (days.DayName) ) as days '))
.then(data=>{ console.log(data) }).catch(err=>{})
```

and the result looks like this :

```json
{
"ages" : "Adult,Teenager"
"days" : "Mon,Tue"
}
```

but I'm looking for a way to show  it like:

```json
{
"ages" : ["Adult","Teenager"]
"days" : ["Mon","Tue"]
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* manually add the square brackets around the values:

```
concat('[', group_concat(distinct ages.AgeTitle), ']')  as ages,
concat('[', group_concat(distinct ages.DayName ), ']')  as days
```

But bottom line: if you want a json output, you can generate it directly from the database - with the one limitation that json aggregate functions do not support `distinct`. If that's acceptable for you, then:

```
json_object(
    'ages', json_arrayagg(ages.AgeTitle),
    'days', json_arrayagg(ages.DayName)
)
```